How to call controller methods/utils during Aura to LWC conversion
We have a campaign Image aura component that uses this Java controller
I am trying to move this to a new LWC component and wanted to know how can I use the controller in my LWC component?
Are the Utils in the controller available via ui-api?
Some of them are serverUrlUtil, recordUtils, filesService etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
